# How can I modify my Ember Addon build based on the template contents?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

I'm working on the [@fortAwesome/ember-fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/ember-fontawesome) addon. I'd like to be able to find the icons that have been used in templates and include the necessary JS into the final build.
Template:
`{{fa-icon icon='bacon'}}`

I can use

```
setupPreprocessorRegistry(type, registry) {
  registry.add('htmlbars-ast-plugin', {
    name: 'font-awesome-detect-static-icons',
    plugin: staticIconDetector,
  });
},
```

This works to discover the icons, but the preprocessors don't do their work until all the other hooks like `postprocessTree` or `treeForVendor` have already run. Is there another way to get at the AST of the templates *before* the other hooks run? Or another way to get at this information?